# Asp.net photo gallery with fancybox not showing next/previos button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, fancybox

I am working on asp.net photo gallery & i am using fancybox-1.3.4 to show images as overlay

It is working fine i have two issue with it.

**One**: It doesn't show the next / previews as show in the screen shot image below
[image]

**Second**: On the main galley i am using Custom Title for the Image i add span tags to it it comes up right when i click on the photo.but on the main gallery page when one hover over the image it show title which has span tags visible. It doesn't come up in the IE.
I have to pass this title to the large overlay image. How can i hide it on the main page.

Comment: I have removed js file which are not used.. But wont work even with that also..

Comment: I have gone through page, I event changed it to group `$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();` but it wont work.. I have missed something..somewhere that is for sure..

Comment: Resolved it i had forgot to mention the `rel="group-images"` so that image can be grouped.

Comment: You can use any term inside rel="Lorem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Galleries are created from elements that share the same `rel` attribute like

   ```
   <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" ...>one</a>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" ...>two</a>
   ```

   etc. (navigation buttons won't appear if there are not at least two or more elements with the same `rel` attribute)
2. You may prefer to get the fancybox `title` from the `alt` attribute of the image (`img`) tag so it won't be shown as *tooltip* when hover the thumbnail. Then add the option (Fancybox v1.3.4) `'titleFromAlt':true` like

   ```
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options here etc
      'titleFromAlt':true 
   });
   ```

Check [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/3da14d88af2393cc/) for reference about fancybox `title` in v1.3.x

Comment: @JKF, You are right.. I resolved the fist issue by grouping the images for second one i did exactly as you said but problem with this is that it only show the Title not the date part. I am not sure why this is happening i will trouble shot it..

Comment: Alt tag of image contains only title of image but not the other details like date etc..

Comment: move what you have as `title` to the `alt` attribute (and remove the `title` attribute afterwards)

Comment: Thanks i resolved worked around your solution & it works fine now.