# Fancybox for youtube custom title not comming up properly

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, webforms

I am working on a Gallery section which has Photos & Video section.

I Every thing is fine with the photo gallery & it is working fine. example: Photo Gallery URL http://tinyurl.com/bsqd5lp

In photo gallery i am using `'titleFromAlt': true,` to pass the title using `alt` tag. alt tag has customized title example `<span>2012-07-02</span><br><span>Department of Tourism</span>`

I want to do same for the video galley but i cant achieve this using `'titleFromAlt': true,`. The way i doing it is not good as it show the title when one hover over the image as HTML code. Example: Video Gallery URL http://tinyurl.com/bsdq694

Other issue i have with this is the title of the video come in center. I tried to change the CSS so that title will be left aligned.

```
.fancybox-title-float {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    height: 32px;
    float:left;
}
```

For some reason i am not able to overnight the above code even if i place this after displaying image.

Help this is regard in appreciated.

UPDATED:

code for you tube videos

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".youtube").click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'title': this.title,
            'titleFromAlt': true,
            //'titlePosition': 'over',
            'width': 680,
            'height': 495,
            'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type': 'swf',
            'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: In the first example (photo gallery) you moved the content of the `title` attribute to the `alt` attribute, do the same here.

Comment: `'padding': 0,
  'autoScale': false,
  'transitionIn': 'none',
  'transitionOut': 'none',
   //'title': this.title,
    'titlePosition': 'over',
   'titleFromAlt': true,
    'width': 680,
   'height': 495,
   'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                'type': 'swf',
                'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }` If i do it like this then title wont show on move hover but it also wont show up with the popup video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that we have overlooked is that for your videos you are using the manual method via `.click()` and not the regular way to bind fancybox to a selector via `.fancybox()`

In this scenario - using `.click()`- the `titleFromAlt` option won't work, however you still can set the fancybox title from the `alt` attribute stored in your `img` tag using a regular jQuery expression.

so try this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".youtube").click(function () {
     // first, get the value from the alt attribute
        var newTitle = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); // NEW
        $.fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
          //'title': this.title, // we will replace this line
            'title' : newTitle,  //<--- this will do the trick
          //'titleFromAlt': true,  // we don't need this anymore
          //'titlePosition': 'over', 
            'width': 680,
            'height': 495,
            'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type': 'swf',
            'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

... assuming that you have an `alt` attribute in the `img` tag.

Sorry for the confusion and all the comments back and forth.

Comment: Absolute beauty... This did the trick & thanks for clear documentation. I have seen other similar example but most of the  lack proper example or clear documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, I could see that the text, which appears in the span tag, appears as well within the title attribute. Try to remove that attribute with the text, and the title text will not appear.

About the second problem:
from the CSS class `.fancybox-title-float`, remove the attribute 'position: absolute;', and from the id `#fancybox-title-float-left`, remove the the 'padding' attribute. After applying those changes your text will align to the left.

Comment: @ukai, I am able to solve the second part with your guidance. But first part is still like that i have removed the `alt` from the image tag but it still shows title on mouse hover & removes title from popup. I hope this is what you wanted to say. I want to hide the title on mouse hover & show it in the popup only

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker : you have to remove the `title` attribute, not the `alt` attribute (and move the content of `title` to `alt`) ... you already did that with your photos on the other post/question. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11390942/1055987

Comment: @JFK, I followed your advice with this approach i am not getting anything on move over but this also remove title from the popup video which was earlier show  below the video. I am not sure what change i need to make to the part of jQuery code i use of you-tube. I have update question wit the code also

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you don't need to change anything on the jQuery, just in the html like `<a class="youtube" href="{to youtube}"><img alt="{the fancybox title here}" src="{thumb}" /></a>` ... you are missing the `alt` attribute on the `img` tag.

Comment: @JKF, This is exactly i did earlier, still it is not working for some reason. anyways i appreciate replies from everybody